# Should I archive and prune data from mysql table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.6

Here is my situation, I have a table with partition on `ScheduleTime` and index on `Id` <strike>and `ScheduleTime`</strike>

```
CREATE TABLE `tab1` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ScheduleTime` datetime NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

ALTER TABLE `tab1` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`);
```

I have only one master (write intensive)  no slave. Table rapidly grows(Currently More than 100M records) but need only current month data. Older data need for historical reference only.
Here I have options:

1. Archive partition which is older than 1 month and delete it from working table
2. Keeps as it is. ( I suspect after billions of rows It would affect performance)

If I choose option 1 then I have options

- Older data archive in another table in same database.
- Maintain another archive database
- Archive as compressed  and store in separate disk

As little knowledge in database I don't know which is best practice or how everyone handle in this situation.

Comment: If you later want to use the data, the archive is not a comfortable option. In this scenario, I think that *partitioning* the table by year-month (and keeping current and previous months alive) is the fittest solution.

Comment: @joanolo Older than month data rarely (probably never) used.

Comment: Then any of the options is reasonable enough. It will mostly depend on whether you have plenty of disk or you don't.

Comment: A billion rows is not necessarily any slower than 100M rows.  Or it could be 10 times as slow.  Please provide samples of all the queries.

Comment: You say there are indexes, but the table definition says there are none; which is it?

Comment: @RickJames  Yes, indexes on `Id`.